# React context with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I want to use a context within my React Typescript project, how can I do that?

I have the following code:
App.js

```
import {Context} from 'context'

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <Router>
       <Context.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
       ... some routes
       </Context.Provider>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Then in my context.js file I have:

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

type ValueContextType = {
  value: string;
  setValue: (value: string) => void;
}

export const ValueContext = createContext<ValueContextType | undefined>(undefined);
```

And I want to use this to set a state in another file. Let's say users.js

```
import {ValueContext} from 'context'

const Users () => {
  const {value, setValue} = useContext(ValueContext);
}
```

Now the problem that both value and setValue have the same error message:

> Property 'setValue' does not exists on type 'ValueContextType | undefined'

How can I make this work?

Comment: where are you defining `setTitle`?

Comment: Sorry, was a mistype! It is setValue. Updated now.

Comment: Without any overview of your solution, this may be overkill; should this be shared by using a Redux store?

Comment: Could not share the whole solution as it consists of 100 files. I am not comfy with redux yet, so context works better for now. But I have posted an answer that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works:

App.js

```
import {Context} from 'context'

const App = () => {
  type ValueContextType = {
  value: string;
  setValue: (value: string) => void;
  }
  const [value, setValue] = useState<ValueContextType | any>("");
  return (
    <Router>
       <Context.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
       ... some routes
       </Context.Provider>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Then in my context.js file I have:

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

type ValueContextType = {
  value: string;
  setValue: (value: string) => void;
}

export const ValueContext = createContext<ValueContextType | any>("");
```

users.js

```
import {ValueContext} from 'context'

const Users () => {
  const {value, setValue} = useContext(ValueContext);
}
```

I don't know if this is "hacky" or not, but it works.

Comment: `const [value, setValue] = useContext(ValueContext);`